# How to blend the same color from a div and ::after? (prevent mixing)

Tags: html, css

I have a box that contains `::after`. The goal that I want to achieve is to prevent mixing the colors. Like in the picture, the color should not darken. Therefore, it should have only one color.

[image]

The parent `div` and the `::after` has the same hex color.

```css
.box {
  background: #2a816c4d;
  color: #000;
  cursor: pointer;
  min-width: 100px;
  height: 36px;
  flex: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
}

.box::after {
  top: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 0;
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  border-top: 19px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 17px solid transparent;
  z-index: 2;
  right: -20px;
  background-color: #2a816c4d;
  clip-path: polygon(20% 0%, 80% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  container
</div>
```

The color was initially written in rgba; I converted it to hex thinking that would fix it, but still no luck.

---

Just want to let you know the final output of this is,

[image]

Comment: Using opaque colors is necessary? Half-treansparent backgrounds will sum, solid colors (try #BFD9D3) will not.

Comment: @Vladimir i understand your suggestion. But I'm not sure if that will display the expected output. Could you post an answer let me see the final colors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd probably approach the problem as follows, with explanatory comments in the code:

```css
/* simple resetting, to remove default margins, and padding
   and also to force browsers to use the same sizing
   algorithm for all elements, including the padding and
   border-widths within the assigned sizes: */
*,
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  padding-block: 1rem;
}

main {
  display: grid;
  gap: 0.5rem;
  inline-size: clamp(50rem, 80%, 1000px);
  margin-inline: auto;
}
/* the above is basically just for aesthetics, and
   largely irrelevant */

/* here we define custom properties for use within
   the content styling: */
section {
  --angle-inset: 1rem;
  --background-color: #2a816c4d;
  --box-height: 2rem;
  --inline-padding: 1rem;
  /* using display flex in order to place
     elements on the inline axis: */
  display: flex;
}

/* setting the shared properties of all .box elements: */
.box {
  background-color: var(--background-color);
  block-size: var(--box-height);
  color: #000;
  cursor: pointer;
  /* the following two lines are a simple means of
     placing the content of an element both vertically,
     and horizontally, centered: */
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
}

/* here we define the :first-child, as that has a slightly
   different appearance to its subsequent siblings: */
.box:first-child {
  /* defining the clip-path, which is how we're creating
     the slope on the end of the element: */
  clip-path:
    polygon(
      /* lower-left vertex; I start with the lower-left
         purely as a matter of preference and custom (you
         can start at any vertex you prefer); here the
         XY coordinates are zero (X) and 100% (Y): */
      0 100%,
      /* upper-left vertex */
      0 0,
      /* upper-right vertex; here we use the calc function,
         and make use of the --angle-inset custom property
         to place the top of the angled slope at 100% (X)
         minus the size of the defined --angle-inset,
         and at zero on the Y axis: */
      calc(100% - var(--angle-inset)) 0,
      /* lower-right vertex */
      100% 100%
    );
  /* this is to ensure that the content isn't positioned against
     either edge of the element, to avoid clipping and ensure a
     balanced layout; because the :first-child only has an angle
     on one edge, we use just the --inline-padding for the first
     (non-angled) side (padding-inline-start), but for the second
     (padding-inline-end) we add the --inline-padding and
     --angle-inset properties together: */
  padding-inline: var(--inline-padding) calc(var(--inline-padding) + var(--angle-inset));
}

.box:first-child~.box {
  clip-path:
    polygon(
      /* lower-left vertex */
      var(--angle-inset) 100%,
      /* upper-left vertex */
      0 0,
      /* upper-right vertex */
      calc(100% - var(--angle-inset)) 0,
      /* lower-right vertex */
      100% 100%
    );
  padding-inline: calc(var(--inline-padding) + var(--angle-inset));
  margin-inline-start: -0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section>
    <div class="box">Container 01</div>
    <div class="box">Container 02</div>
    <div class="box">Container 03</div>
    <div class="box">Container 04</div>
    <div class="box">Container 05</div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <div class="box">Container 01</div>
    <div class="box">Container 02</div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <div class="box">Container 01</div>
    <div class="box">Container 02</div>
    <div class="box">Container 03</div>
  </section>
</main>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/kh8e6dys/).

Answer (score 0):

A valid hex value is only 6 characters but you are using 8.

Try using a RGBA value and adjust the opacity as desired.

```css
.box {
  background: rgba(42, 129, 108, 1);
  color: #000;
  cursor: pointer;
  min-width: 100px;
  height: 36px;
  flex: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
}

.box::after {
  top: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 0;
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  border-top: 19px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 17px solid transparent;
  z-index: 2;
  right: -20px;
  background-color: rgba(42, 129, 108, 1);
  clip-path: polygon(20% 0%, 80% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  container
</div>
```

Comment: thats a different color :). You know I also wanna use solid colors. But its client request.

Comment: "*A valid hex value is only 6 characters but you are using 8*" - you may want to check out "[CSS color module level 4](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-color/#hex-notation)," although Chrome supported 4/8-digit Boston since version 52 (or similar, and Firefox from around the same time).

Comment: If it is a solid color you are after, just change ``` background: rgba(42, 129, 108, 1);``` to ```background-color: #2a816c``` or whatever you color is.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your desired output by just finding the solid color equivalent of the opaque color.
I changed it to this color:

```
background-color: #b2d4cc;
```

Let me know if it helped!